# Calling template member function with variadic arguments, function argument and non-argument template-parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to use a template member function defined as:

```
  template <class HeaderClass, typename ...Args>
  void LoaderClass::loadHeader(std::function<HeaderClass(Args&&...)> headerGenerator, Args&&... argsForGenerator) {
    // stuff
    auto hdrPtr = new HeaderClass(headerGenerator(std::forward<Args>(argsForGenerator)...));
    /// more stuff
}
```

Essentially, I want to call this function which can take functions that create instances of a variety of classes (all subclasses of a base one, fwiw) from a variable set of arguments.

The specified function compiles just fine on GCC 9.x, but I can't figure out the right way to call it. I found many similar examples while searching, although none dealt with the case of the HeaderClass template parameter not being used directly in the function signature. Anyway, from those similar examples, I have tried:

```
SpecialHeader headerMaker(int arg1, std::string arg2, float arg3) {
   // create and return a SpecialHeader instance
}

loader.loadHeader(&headerMaker, 1, "whatever", 3.5);  // Doesn't work, with or without &
loader.loadHeader<SpecialHeader>(&headerMaker, 1, "whatever", 3.5);  // Doesn't work
loader.template loadHeader<SpecialHeader>(&headerMaker, 1, "whatever", 3.5);  // Doesn't work
```

In every case, I get an error with some variation of `candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<SpecialHeader (type-parameter-0-1 &&...)>' against 'SpecialHeader (*)(int, string, float)'`.

So my question is, how exactly do I make a valid call to my function? Surely I could not have created something uncallable, could I?

Comment: Drop `std::function` and replace it with a simple `typename F`, `F &&func`. Either determine `HeaderClass` using `decltype`, or just do `auto hdrPtr = new auto(...);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Is `new auto(...)` a valid syntax ?

Comment: @Mechap It seems so: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thought it was linked with a recent proposal added to c++23 [P0849R8](https://wg21.link/P0849R8)

Comment: @Mechap That proposal adds a standalone `auto(...)` cast, usable everywhere. `new auto` is different, and was already allowed (since C++11 if cppreference is correct).